# NSPredicate Exact Match with String

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsstring, nspredicate

I have a NSPredicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name CONTAINS %@", myString];
```

But that will return anything which contains that string. For example:
If my entity.name's where:

```
text
texttwo
textthree
randomtext
```

and the `myString` was `text` then all of those strings would match. I would like it so that if `myString` is `text` it would only return the first object with the name `text` and if `myString` was `randomtext` it would return the fourth object with the name `randomtext`. I am also looking for it to be case **insensitive** and that it ignores whitespace

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This should do it:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name LIKE[c] %@", myString];
```

`LIKE` matches strings with ? and * as wildcards. The `[c]` indicates that the comparison should be case insensitive.

If you don't want ? and * to be treated as wildcards, you can use `==` instead of `LIKE`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name ==[c] %@", myString];
```

More info in the NSPredicate Predicate Format String Syntax [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB).

Comment: Ahh, sorry I missed that part. I think for whitespace insensitivity, you must use MATCHES and provide a regular expression instead of a simple match string. dasblinkenlight's answer demonstrates this.

Answer (score 13):

You can use regular expression matcher with your predicate, like this:

```
NSString *str = @"test";
NSMutableString *arg = [NSMutableString string];
[arg appendString:@"\\s*\\b"];
[arg appendString:str];
[arg appendString:@"\\b\\s*"];
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF matches[c] %@", arg];
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" test ", @"test", @"Test", @"TEST", nil];
NSArray *b = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

The piece of code above constructs a regular expression that matches strings with optional blanks at the beginning and/or at the end, with the target word surrounded by the "word boundary" markers `\b`. The `[c]` after `matches` means "match case-insensitively".

This example uses an array of strings; to make it work in your environment, replace `SELF` with `entity.name`.

Comment: It's good, it works, but if you're going to use `matches`, then you may not want to match the spaces explicitly (in case you're going to perform substitution), and for that you can simplify both your `@"\\s*\\b"` and `@"\\b\\s*"` to `@"\\b"` directly: `NSString *arg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\b", str];`