# Sorting NSMutableArray based on Key with Predicates not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have a NSMutableArray with more than 150+ objects, and i need to create a new Array based on this key "name" matching with input name.

So i got this predicate code from stackoverflow

```
    NSMutableArray *listForm=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //copy Original Array
    listForm=[arr valueForKey:@"data"]; //copied
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == [c] %@", [selectedDrug valueForKey:@"name"]]; //checking name 

    NSLog(@"%@",[selectedDrug valueForKey:@"name"]); //my input name for matching

    [listForm filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];  


    NSLog(@"%@",listForm);//final result
```

NOw am getting correct results but along with that am getting extra objects

like for example
 Consider this is my big list of object

```
[{
  name:"john",
  location:"washington",
  age:23
},{
  name:"Zirad kan",
  location:"iceland",
  age:23
},{
  name:"john",
  location:"usa",
  age:43
},{
  name:"riya",
  location:"india",
  age:20
},{
  name:"Rachel",
  location:"netherland",
  age:33
},{
  name:"john Mark",
  location:"washington",
  age:23
},{
  name:"john Doe",
  location:"washington",
  age:23
}]
```

From this i need All name exactly matching to "john"

so the result will be like this

```
 [{
      name:"john",
      location:"washington",
      age:23
    },{
      name:"john",
      location:"usa",
      age:43
    }]
```

But when i use above code iam getting this as final result

```
 [{
      name:"john",
      location:"washington",
      age:23
    },{
      name:"john",
      location:"usa",
      age:43
    },{
      name:"john Mark",
      location:"washington",
      age:23
    },{
      name:"john Doe",
      location:"washington",
      age:23
    }]
```

How can i remove  "John Doe" and "John Mark "  like i need only a specific text matching "john".

Pls help me

Comment: see this link may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597508/nspredicate-exact-match-with-string

Comment: `predicateWithBlock:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate:) returns the filtered array, so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == [c] %@",
    selectedDrug[@"name"]]; 
NSArray *filtered = [arr[@"data"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Note: this assumes both `arr` and `selectedDrug` are `NSDictionary` instances.

Comment: let me try this now itself