# Who can explain this NSPredicate syntax

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have this predicate:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF LIKE[cd] %@", searchString)
```

which I'm using for filtering array and finding the needed string.

Could you explain what this argument "**SELF LIKE[cd] %@**" means?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11597537/5389870).

Comment: `[cd]` is case and diacritic insensitive, everything else is described in [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, `NSPredicate(format:)` is like `String(format:)`, so the `%@` is replaced with the contents of `searchString`.

`[cd]` means **c**ase and **d**iacritic insensitive - so `john Jonés` would match `John Jones`

`LIKE` is used to match with a wildcard (* = 0 or more chars, ? = 1 character). so `LIKE Joh*` would match with `John Jones`

Comment: Respect for your comprehensive answer, Ashley! :-)